# How can I bootstrap CakePHP 1.3 in PHPUnit

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-1.3

I am currently working with a legacy CakePHP 1.3 application and would like to start adding tests as I go.

While I am aware that CakePHP has its own test classes which, in 1.3x use SimpleTest, we would prefer to use PHPUnit throughout due to existing experience.

My questions are basically, is it possible? and if so how do I bootstrap the CakePHP framework within the test suite so that tests can access models/controllers etc.

Comment: Marked to close, although the accepted answer on that question doesn't seem to solve the problem I will continue to look for help via that thread.

Comment: Is this a new project? I would really consider going to CakePHP 2.x. It really has improved a lot, and (as you mentioned) uses PhpUnit. You can try to upgrade your project with the [Upgrade Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html#upgrade-shell), but be sure to do this on a copy :)

Comment: Thanks thaJeztah, its already on the roadmap, but this app has somewhere around 200K loc spread across 15+ custom plugins.  Its not a walk in the park to upgrade and we wanted to try and get some tests in place first.

Comment: Understandable. Just wanted to add is as an option to consider :)